# How to bulk download from google app engine dev app server

Tags: python, google-app-engine

The documentation online implies that data can be downloaded from the development server (just one kind at-a-time:

> Downloading all entities of all kinds only works on App Engine, and does not work with the development server.

Should the url switch be passed with localhost as the argument? I've searched and continue to search but can find no examples.

```
    appcfg.py download_data --application=<your_app_id> --kind=<kind>
    --url=http://your_app_id.appspot.com/[remote_api_path]
    --filename=<data-filename>
```

I have added into the app.yaml:

```
    builtins:
    - remote_api: on
```

What is the remote_api_path if you have enabled the remote_api builtin?

I hope someone can provide an example of command-line arguments that will allow bulk-downloading of data for specific kinds.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with something like this:

```
appcfg.py download_data 
    --application=YourAppID --kind=YourKind
    --url=http://localhost:YourPort/_ah/remote_api 
    --filename=YourFileName
```

Comment: that's the remote_path i was looking for... thank you - it got me past authentication. i have some new errors but that's my responsibility to track down... thanks again...